# How to make an a .desktop file for an .sh file

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have a problem creating a .desktop file for a .sh file but I can't run it. I am running Linux mint and I created the .desktop file using `gnome-desktop-item-edit`

My script.sh file has this code:

```
sudo java -jar /opt/folder/files.jar
```

and my .desktop file contains this

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=sudo java -jar /opt/folder/script.sh
Name=script
Comment=do this and that
```

It works properly if I run the sh file in the terminal but not by using the desktop file.

Comment: Exec should call the script, not java as root

Answer (score 1):

In the `Exec=` line of your desktop file you call `java -jar somescript.sh`, which will never work, since `java` is the command to launch the java application. You therefore need to call `sudo java -jar /opt/folder/files.jar` in this line directly.
Or you call the script instead: `bash /opt/folder/script.sh`.

### So either:

```
Exec=sudo java -jar /opt/folder/files.jar
```

### or:

```
Exec=bash /opt/folder/script.sh
```

Comment: Or just call the script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the script, not java.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=bash -c "/opt/folder/script.sh"
Name=script
Comment=do this and that
```